Offline Installation of Android Studio Dependencies
I'm learning Android Studio and want to set up a development environment for an offline computer. When I try to do the initial install, it always tries to download dependencies and other files from the internet. Additionally, when Gradle builds a project, it downloads more files, which doesn't work for me since the machine needs to remain offline.
Is there a way to download all the necessary Android SDK files and Gradle dependencies in advance so that I can use them later without needing to connect to the internet? Any methods or tools you can share would be really helpful.
Thanks

The simplest solution would seem to be to do a complete build first online, before taking the machine offline. Android Studio used to have an offline mode, though I am not seeing it in a quick glance at the Ladybug version. If you can enable that, it should stop Studio itself from trying to download stuff. Gradle caches dependencies on first use, so doing a complete build (and then not updating the dependency versions while offline) should meet your needs.

If you are able to initially connect the computer to the internet:
Open the project in Android Studio while being connected to the internet and let it download all dependencies. Afterwards, enable the offline mode for Gradle, so that Gradle will directly fetch all dependencies from the Gradle cache in the future:

If you can't connect the computer to the internet at all:
First, open the project on a computer that has internet connection and let it download all dependencies. The dependencies will be put into the Gradle cache that by default is located under the following path:
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1

You can create a zip file of that directory and paste it in the same location of the target computer. Then, when starting Android Studio on the target computer, enable the Gradle offline mode as described above.
Note:
When in offline mode, make sure not to update any library versions, as then the build will immediately fail because the new version is not in the Gradle cache.

Is there a repository that can be downloaded once, allowing Gradle to build offline?

Not that I know of. I spent hours on the same issue, the only thing I got working was using the method I described by copying the gradle cache. In the past, there seemed to be an offline version of Android Studio, but it was not continued.
